# Add filter or where condition to MDX query?

Tags: mdx

It should not be one difficult problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to solve it:

```
SELECT {[Source].[Source].CHILDREN, [Source].[Source].[All]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY(
    [Account].[Hierarchy].[Account Type].&[Assets].CHILDREN) 
 ON ROWS  
FROM [Test] 
WHERE ([Measures].[Amount])
```

It works well for all the year.

Now I want to add one time condition such as

```
[Date].[Date].&[2005-10-03T00:00:00]:[Date].[Date].&[2005-12-30T00:00:00]
```

or

```
[Date].[Period].&[Oct 2005],[Date].[Period].&[Nov 2005],[Date].[Period].&[Dec 2005]
```

Can you give me some help?

Comment: What happens when you make that change? More information please.

Comment: Please format your code when asking questions; it makes the question much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these queries:

```
SELECT {[Source].[Source].CHILDREN, [Source].[Source].[All]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY
    [Account].[Hierarchy].[Account Type].&[Assets].CHILDREN
 ON ROWS  
FROM [Test] 
WHERE CrossJoin({[Measures].[Amount]}, [Date].[Date].&[2005-10-03T00:00:00]:[Date].[Date].&[2005-12-30T00:00:00])
```

or

```
SELECT {[Source].[Source].CHILDREN, [Source].[Source].[All]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY
    [Account].[Hierarchy].[Account Type].&[Assets].CHILDREN
 ON ROWS  
FROM [Test] 
WHERE CrossJoin({[Measures].[Amount]}, {[Date].[Period].&[Oct 2005],[Date].[Period].&[Nov 2005],[Date].[Period].&[Dec 2005]})
```